# Fill model value from an object.

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, loops

I am trying to create a function that receives an array and an object and returns a combination of the two like so.

```
fruits: [
  {
    name: apple,
    seeds: ''
  },
  {
    name: grape,
    seeds: ''
  },
  { name: banana,
    seeds: ''
  },
]

const seedData = {
  apple: 'yes',
  banana: 'yes',
  grape: 'no',
}

setSeedData = (fruits, seedData) => {
  return completedFruits
}
```

Wanted result is like so:

```
fruits: [
  {
    name: apple,
    seeds: 'yes'
  },
  {
    name: grape,
    seeds: 'yes'
  },
  { 
    name: banana,
    seeds: 'no'
  },
]
```

My question is: How do I create the function setSeedData? De array returned should replace the current fruits array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could basically map over the array and return the updated data

```js
const fruits= [
  {
    name: 'apple',
    seeds: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'grape',
    seeds: ''
  },
  { name: 'banana',
    seeds: ''
  },
]

const seedData = {
  apple: 'yes',
  banana: 'yes',
  grape: 'no',
}

setSeedData = (fruits, seedData) => {
  return fruits.map(fruit=> ({...fruit, seeds: seedData[fruit.name]}));
}

console.log(setSeedData(fruits, seedData));
```

Comment: Thanks really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.forEach()` to iterate over array and add properties:

```js
const fruits = [
  {name: 'apple', seeds: ''},
  {name: 'grape', seeds: ''},
  {name: 'banana', seeds: ''}
];

const seedData = {
  apple: 'yes',
  banana: 'yes',
  grape: 'no'
};

const setSeedData = (arr, obj) => (arr.forEach((o) => (o.seeds = obj[o.name])), arr);

console.log(setSeedData(fruits, seedData));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map over the `fruits`, and the update the `seeds` key by looking up the `seedData` object with `name` key value of `fruits`.

```js
const fruits = [
  {
    name: 'apple',
    seeds: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'grape',
    seeds: ''
  },
  { name: 'banana',
    seeds: ''
  },
];

const seedData = {
  apple: 'yes',
  banana: 'yes',
  grape: 'no',
}

setSeedData = (fruits, seedData) => {
  return fruits.map(fruit => {
    return {...fruit, seeds: seedData[fruit.name]}
  })
}

console.log(setSeedData(fruits, seedData))
```